# Efficient quantum circuit to prepare a set off entangled state

Tags: quantum-information, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

If I try to prepare an entangled state on $N$ pairs of qubits ($2N$ qubits) as $$|\psi\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{2^N}w_i|ii\rangle , $$ 
with $w_i$ real factors, is there an efficient quantum circuit to achieve this starting from an initial separable state $|000...0\rangle$ of the $2N$ qubits?

Due to the exponential number of non-structured parameters $\{w_i\}$, I assume this should be difficult. Is this the case?

Comment: There is an inconsistency here. A tensor product $|000...0\rangle$ is not the same as a superposition $\sum_i |ii\rangle w_i$. Hence, one cannot lead to the other.

Comment: The state $\lvert\psi\rangle$ you write is *not* a state on $2N$ qubits, but a state on 2 qubits (or I don't understand the notation). Is there a typo?

Comment: agree with @glS That's a 2 qudits (not even bits) wavefunction with each having $2^N$ internal d.o.f. You might make the notation clearer.

Comment: It's still a two-qudit state

Comment: @glS Except for sloppy notation, it's all fine.  $2N$ qubits are 2 qudits with $d=2^N$.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no efficient circuit in general.  As you point out yourself, your output state has an exponential number of complex parameters, which requires an exponential-length circuit simply by counting parameters.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I made a mistake. What if I want  N qubit in a mixed state with a diagonal reduced density matrix$\rho=diag(p_1,p_2,....,p_{2^N})? Is this a simple state that can be obtained by tracing out N qubits from  a simple pure 2N qubit state?  It seems this is the same as my question, right?  My brain  halts, too sleepy.

Comment: Please fix the question, and avoid endless follow-up question (which seems to be a habit of yours).

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly you want a circuit which transforms N-qubit state |000...0> to an arbitrary superposition of all possible states of N qubits. If so, as far as I know there is no actual sequence of gates that would perform efficient (in terms of number of these gates) transformation. This is a problem which was presented in DiVincenzo's criteria for physical implementations of quantum computers. So I guess exact circuit and it's efficiency would depend on actual physical platform of the system you use.

Comment: This answer is not correct: It is clear that this is impossible, simply by counting parameters.

Comment: I actually stated the same thing "If so, as far as I know there is no actual sequence of gates that would perform efficient (in terms of number of these gates) transformation". All I wanted to say is that complexity of a real implementation could depend on physical platform.